# How can i get this Script to run onEdit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get this to run automatically, however with the current form it only works if i manually run the code.

I have another code file in this sheet which also uses onEdit, how can I incorporate the same onEdit to this code or make it run whenever column G is selected "Complete" to then change column H to "shipped"

```html
function addValidation() {

  // Get the spreadsheet and active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Get the data as an Array you can iterate and manipulate
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(["Complete"]).build();

  // Loop the sheet
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {


    if(data[i][11] == "Complete") {


      sheet.getRange(i+1, 8).clear().setDataValidation(rule);

    }  {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 8).clearDataValidations().setValue("Shipped");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem/clarification needed about the answer? I ask because you didn't make any comment and it's not accepted yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

In your `if` statement, you're not checking Column G - you're checking column K (11). If you want to check G, you need to change your if to:

```js
if(data[i][6].toString() == "Complete") {
  ...
}
```

Your logic is backward and you're missing the `else` keyword to run the alternative. As is, it will mark 'Shipped' if it *doesn't* match 'Complete.' Swap the statements to fill the cell values correctly.

Also, string checking in a loop is a little tricky. Cell references as indices are *objects*, not strings. You need to convert your cell using the `.toString()` method before you can compare a straight string.

Your whole script should read:

```js
  function addValidation() {

  // Get the spreadsheet and active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Get the data as an Array you can iterate and manipulate
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  // Loop the sheet
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

    // To change which columns you're testing, change the second value.
    // ColG = 6, not 11.
    // Convert data[i][6] using .toString() to compare the value
    if(data[i][6].toString() == "Complete") {

      // If it's "Complete," mark Col H as 'Shipped'
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue("Shipped");

    } else {
      // If you want something else to happen, add that here.
    }
  }
}
```

The last step is to enable a trigger for the script. If you name your function `onEdit()`, it will run by itself because editing is a simple script. Since it's called `addValidation`, you need to manually add the `onEdit` trigger in the UI. Go to Edit > Current Project Triggers and click on "Add Trigger" in the bottom right. Follow the steps in the UI and the script should run itself.